# HTTP authentication on Windows intranet ok from browsers, not from other web clients

Tags: windows, authentication, networking

I want to write a crawler to extract information from a corporate website that is accessible only from the company intranet.
I can access that website from any browser installed on my laptop, but I get an HTTP401 when I try to do this from any other web client (curl, nodejs request, ...).

I've tried to play with different settings related to proxy and basic auth but I could not find any solution that works.

As I'm on a Windows system and I think IE network settings may be involved here, I've also tried to get the network proxy settings from IE with 
`netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie`, but it did not make any difference.

What have I missed? How can I determine what make local browsers able to reach that website and not other web clients? I've had a look at the request in Chrome developer tools but was not able to find anything that could help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.  I was missing the `--ntlm` flag in `curl`.

```
$ curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -u "${USER}:${PASS}" ${URL}
401
$ curl --ntlm -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -u "${USER}:${PASS}" ${URL}
200
```